Matplotlib warning due to multiple versions: how to handle this in Ubuntu 24?
So Ubuntu 24LTS recently came out and it uses Python3.12 as the systemwide python version. Starting from 23, we now cannot really "play" with the default installation: we cannot install python3.12 packages locally with pip. That is ok, it is safer.
I installed python3.11 and I want to use it locally to run my scripts. In this specific case I would prefer to not use virtual environments. For python3.11, I installed packages locally with
python3.11 -m pip install --user --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
because I would like to not rely on systemwide installations. I simply want to have python3.11 use local packages, without conflicting with Ubuntu python3.12
When I run:
python3.11 -c "import matplotlib.pyplot"

I get this warning:
/home/<user>local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of Matplotlib being installed (e.g. as a system package and as a pip package). As a result, the 3D projection is not available.
  warnings.warn("Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of "

I would like to prevent python3.11 to use systemwide packages, without a virtual environment. Is it possible? Would it be easy and advisable, in this case, to permanently remove /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ from the python3.11 path?
Thank you very much.

"In this specific case I would prefer to not use virtual environments."  Why?  This would solve your issue.

Indeed it would solve the issue... but I'm still curious about this problem. Isn't it a sort of a flaw in Ubuntu design that there is a conflict between two different python installations?

From discussion at the relevant GitHub issue, I think all you can really do is remove Matplotlib from the dist-packages.  Or, if you do not need 3D plotting or other mpl_toolkits features, you could just live with the warning. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26827

Thanks! Is it safe to remove the systemwide installation of Matplotlib then? Is it essential to Ubuntu?

Dear @RuthC, in the link you posted, they recommend removing the systemwide matplotlib, and then uninstall and install the pip matplotlib.
I have tried this solution in two computers, it has been a few days and it has worked fine, I believe Ubuntu does not really need the systemwide matplotlib? Since you were the one who suggested the link above, if you want to write a simple answer here I would gladly accept it as the correct answer!
